# Regarding the graphical display of 'silence' on the DSP processor

Tags: signal-processing

Why is it that silence doesn't show a Zero value on the graph in Code composer studio for DSK6713 when nothing is said on the microphone?Logically when nothing is said on the mike, no voltage amplitude should be shown on the graph,but it doesn't happen so!...
Please reciprocate as early as possible with the answer.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Even in a quiet environment a microphone emits some signal, and an A/D convertor is going to return non-zero data values. You could apply a noise gate filter if you want this to become zero values.